# Nesting a navigation controller inside another view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have an ios app that is running on the navigation controller and all the view controllers of every navigation base application are being managed by this navigation controller.

Unfortunately whenever I enter a new screen, the whole app interface slides over, see this video:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxYOAz86zlLveFk2aHBSLUtVYVU/edit?usp=sharing

It would be better if only the middle section was the only thing that slides:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxYOAz86zlLvMGluRnNtQVRETEk/edit?usp=sharing

The header:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxYOAz86zlLvLTNnVmVwdnJLV00/edit?usp=sharing
should also not move between transitions.

Any advice on how I can change the view structures of the app to make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible use child view controllers (Embed Segue in storyboard). Then have the header and footer such as navigation and menu as outside and the tableview's viewcontroller as the subview.

Here's an example I swiped from google image search[image]

Comment: Please note: this is only available in iOS6 upwards, but is the most elegant solution if that is ok. I have used it myself and it works great.

Comment: Trying so hard not to suggest calling "Guacamole" by its name, you've got the room on the button...